# Need help finding the range(A)

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having trouble remembering how to find the range.  Any help would be great
Thanks

Let $ \mathbf{A} \ = \ \left(\begin{array}{cc}1&-1&1\\0&1&2\\-1&2&2 \end{array}\right) $ and $ \mathbf{b} \ = \ \left(\begin{array}{cc}5\\1\\2 \end{array}\right) \ . $

A)Determine whether **b** is in Range(**A**)

B)If **b** is in Range (**A**), then exhibit a vector **x** such that **Ax** = **b** .

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbf{b}$ is in the range of $A$ if there are values $s,t,u$ where

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\0\\-1
\end{pmatrix}s+
\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\1\\2
\end{pmatrix}t+
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\2\\2
\end{pmatrix}u=
\mathbf{b}=
\begin{pmatrix}
5\\1\\2
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Turn this into a system of equations.

$$\begin{matrix}
s&-t&+u&=&5\\
&t&+2u&=&1\\
-s&+2t&+2u&=&2
\end{matrix}$$

If you get a solution, then $\mathbf{b}$ is in the range of $A$ and $(s,t,u)$ is your vector $\mathbf{x}$.

Answer (score 0):

The range of a matrix, $A$ is simply the space spanned by the columns of $A$. So, if a vector, $b$ is in the range of matrix $A$ it means that $b$ can be expressed as some linear combination of the columns $A$. But, notice that multiplying the matrix $A$ on the left by a vector, $x$ is a short hand notation for a linear combination of the columns of $A$. In simple terms, part A) of your question simply asks is there a solution, $x$ to the system of equations represented by $Ax = b$? and part B) asks essentially the same question, if  there is a solution, what is it? So let's find a solution to $Ax = b$. The easiest, most direct approach is perhaps: form the augmented matrix $A|b$, do gaussian elimination followed  by back substitution and  answer both parts of the question at once.

$$ A|b = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc|c}1&-1&1&5\\0&1&2&1\\-1&2&2&2 \end{array} \right] \Rightarrow \left[ \begin{array}{ccc|c}1&-1&1&5\\0&1&2&1\\0&1&3&7 \end{array} \right] \Rightarrow \left[ \begin{array}{ccc|c}1&-1&1&5\\0&1&2&1\\0&0&1&6 \end{array} \right] $$
and now, use back substitution to find the solution. Starting in the last row and working back up to the top row, I get...
$$ \begin{align} x_3 &= 6 \\
x_2 +2x_3 &= 1 \\
x_1 - x_2 + x_3 &= 5 \end{align}$$

Now solve for $X$.